# Changing background color on drop-down menu - mobile

Tags: html, css, menu

[image]For this URL: https://www.losangelesinjurycenter.net/, I have the strangest issue. The background color of the drop-down menu on mobile is supposed to be dark blue (like the top header area). But for some unknown reason, it's now white (with white font).

It's supposed to take the color (#00203e ) from this id: #full-width-header. But for some reason, it's not.

CSS

```
#full-width-header {
    background: #00203e none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #c0c0c0;
    padding: 15px 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

It used to look like this on mobile drop-down - https://www.losangeleslegalcenter.net/.

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 1100px)
.menu {
width: 100%;
border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
lear: both; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu show_menu"><li id="menu-item-15631" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15631"><a href="https://www.losangelesinjurycenter.net/about/">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-15628" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-15628"><a href="#">Categories</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-15691" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-15691"><a href="https://www.losangelesinjurycenter.net/category/personal-injury/">Personal Injury</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-15633" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15633"><a href="https://www.losangelesinjurycenter.net/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Instead of URL, provide a screen shot of your problem

Comment: I added image per your feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For now your dropdown doesn't have it's own element, it's actually a part of the `body` (here I added red `background-color` to `body` element for demonstration):

[image]

There are 2 ways:

1. Use change `background-color` of the `body` element (but it will affect other styles, as you can see, the article is red too, and it doesn't seem like a good way).
2. Recreate your dropdown, wrap it in HTML element which you can style without affecting articles and other elements.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I see what you mean. On this one: https://www.losangeleslegalcenter.net/, it takes the color from #full-width-header. It's odd that it doesn't work the same here, as it's basically a clone.